# Google Website Optimizer Cross-Domain Tracking - Outbound Link Doesn't Work

Tags: cross-domain, tagging, google-website-optimizer

I'm trying to get google website optimizer (gwo) cross-domain tracking working with the asynchronous code described here: http://www.google.com/support/websiteoptimizer/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=151978

My outbound link looks like this:

`<a href="http://secure.ultracart.com" onclick="_gaq.push(['_link', 'http://secure.ultracart.com']); return false;">link</a>`

But when I click on that outbound link, it doesn't go to the other website. It works if I remove the  **return false;**, but that stops the gwo conversion from registering.

I thought it might be a javascript conflict, so I made this simple test file, and it still doesn't work: http://www.smilinggardener.com/files/test.php

Is there someone here familiar with gwo who knows what the problem might be? If you look at the page source of my test.php, I think the code is perfect. Thanks very much for any advice you can give me.

Phil

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the onclick event to:

```
onclick="_gaq.push(['**gwo.**_link', 'http://secure.ultracart.com']); return false;"
```

Google's documentation for the cross domain GWO tests is really terrible.  You need to add the 'gwo.' to the '_link' method because that's how the variables are set in the GWO tracking scripts.  Google's actually documentation on this does not show the 'gwo.', which is nice.